# Could not find PROTOBUF Compiler

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, ubuntu-16.04, caffe

I'm trying to do a CMake with Caffe, but my system cannot find protobuf compiler. I have previously installed protobuf2.7.0. Now I switched back to 2.6.1. How could I configure my CMake to recognize the protobuf2.6.1 compiler?

I have done

```
$ sudo apt-get install  libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.6.1
```

But when I try to cmake Caffe, it still gives me the error

```
user@user-computer:~/caffe/build$ cmake -DBLAS=open ..
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so)
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so)
CMake Error at cmake/ProtoBuf.cmake:13 (message):
  Could not find PROTOBUF Compiler
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:43 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following command worked for me.

```
 apt-get install protobuf-compiler
```

Comment: Problem solved. I need to remove the whole build directory I compiled before. And, recreate the build directory and do the cmake -DBLAS=open .. again. Then, it will be able to find the protobuf-compiler

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem. I solved it by running following commands：

```
sudo apt-get remove protobuf-compiler
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler
```

I had tried to run just the second command, but it doesn't work.